# Formal proof formatting in Latex

Tags: formatting, indentation

Here is what I intend to achieve

```
1.r                             (Given)
2.(t ∧ r) → s                   (Given)
3.(p → t) → (q → ¬s)            (Given)
    4.t ∧ r                     (Assumption)
```

Here is what I got:

[image]

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\def\imp{\rightarrow}

\begin{document}

\section{formal proof}
\textbf{(a)}
\begin{proof}
    \begin{align*}
    &1. r& &&\text{(Given)}\\
    &2. (t \land r) \imp s&  &&\text{(Given)}\\
    &3. (p \imp t) \imp (q \imp \neg s)& &&\text{(Given)}\\
    &&4. t \land r& &&\text{(Assumption)}
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

The problem:

How to do the indentation inside a formal proof? I don't mind if the text on the right is not lined up perfectly, but I'd like to have the indentation correct. The indentation produced by the above code is too big.

As you probably can tell, I am new to LaTex. Any suggestions are appreciated. It would be also nice if there's some package for this kind of thing.

Thanks!

**Edit**

A complete formal proof would be something like:

```
1.r                             (Given)
2.(t ∧ r) → s                   (Given)
3.(p → t) → (q → ¬s)            (Given)
    4.t ∧ r                     (Assumption)
    5.t                         (From 4)
    6.s                         (From 2, 4)
        7. (p → t)              (Assumption)
        8. p                    (From 5, 7)
        ...
    ...
...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks! I just would like to have the problem solved! Latex is awesome, but it is sometimes sophisticated

Comment: There are specialist packages for this. What does a completed sub-proof look like in the system? Or which textbook are you using?

Comment: @cfr you can checkout what I edited just now. Basically just a bunch of indentations.

Comment: It is easiest to start with a package designed for a system as close to the one you are using as possible. I'm guessing that one of the Fitch packages will be closest.  Probably `lplfitch` although your example does not show any rules. But the indentation matches and I'm guessing you don't have boxed sub-proofs.

Comment: @ctf Ya, I guess that is the one

Comment: OK. Then `lplfitch` is probably the best starting point, unless there's something out there I'm not aware of. Take a look [here](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/) in case.

Comment: I'm assuming that the letters should not be in italics, even though you don't mention that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\def\imp{\rightarrow}

\newenvironment{level}%
{\addtolength{\itemindent}{2em}}%
{\addtolength{\itemindent}{-2em}}

\begin{document}

\section{formal proof}
\textbf{(a)}
\begin{proof}\leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $r$ \hfill(Given)
    \begin{level}
    \item $(t \land r) \imp s$ \hfill (Given)
    \item $(p \imp t) \imp (q \imp \neg s)$ \hfill(Given)
      \begin{level}
        \item $(p \imp t) \imp (q \imp \neg s)$ \hfill(Given)
        \item $(p \imp t) \imp (q \imp \neg s)$ \hfill(Given)
      \end{level}
    \item $(p \imp t) \imp (q \imp \neg s)$ \hfill(Given)
    \end{level}
    \item $t \land r$ \hfill (Assumption)
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

In this case, the environment `level` increases the item indent on the list and decreases it automatically. You can change the length by changing the `2em` size.

[image]

Comment: THIS IS SOOO AWESOME! the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` and `enumitem`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\def\imp{\rightarrow}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{formal proof}
\textbf{(a)}
\begin{proof}\leavevmode
    \begin{enumerate}[ref=\arabic*]
    \item $r$ \hfill(Given)
    \item $(t \land r) \imp s$ \hfill (Given)\label{enum:second}
    \item $(p \imp t) \imp (q \imp \neg s)$ \hfill(Given)
    \begin{enumerate}[start=4,label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
    \item $t \land r$ \hfill (Assumption)\label{enum:fourth}
    \item $t$ \hfill         (From~\ref{enum:fourth})\label{enum:fifth}
    \item $s$ \hfill          (From~\ref{enum:second},~\ref{enum:fourth})
    \begin{enumerate}[start=7,label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*]
    \item $(p \imp t)$ \hfill   (Assumption)\label{enum:seventh}
     \item $p$  \hfill          (From~\ref{enum:fifth},~\ref{enum:seventh})
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I have used `\label` and `\ref` mechanism for references. To tweak the distances further, please refer to `enumitem` package manual (available at www.texdoc.net)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this is not what I want to achieve. I want the `4.` to be indented once. How am I going to do that?

Comment: @zkytony Do you want 4 to move to right?

Comment: Yea. But not too much. Just a normal 4 space would be perfect. I have added an example of how the whole proof may look like. I think it's just adding a tab (and keep the right side aligned), which shouldn't be very hard..

Comment: @zkytony Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I don't know if @zkytony is bothered about this as it isn't in the question, but the letters should not be in italics. At least, most systems use italics for something else. (You'd want italics if these were variables but they are not.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be best to use a package designed for typesetting this kind of proof. `lplfitch` is probably closest. It draws rules to mark the scopes but these can be eliminated with the help of `etoolbox`. The following patches the main proof command `\fitchprf` so that the rules have 0pt for the duration of the proof. The regular width of rules in tabulars is restored at the end.

`lplfitch` also offers a range of facilities designed to ease the typesetting of such proofs. For example, it defines a range of logical symbols with appropriate spacing. (See the manual for details.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{lplfitch}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength\savearrayrulewidth
\setlength\savearrayrulewidth{\arrayrulewidth}
\pretocmd{\fitchprf}{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0pt}}{\typeout{Great!}}{\typeout{Oh, no!}}
\apptocmd{\fitchprf}{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{\savearrayrulewidth}}{\typeout{Great!}}{\typeout{Oh, no!}}
\begin{document}

\fitchprf{%
  \pline[1]{r}[(Given)]\\
  \pline[2]{(t \land r) \lif s}[(Given)]\\
  \pline[3]{(p \lif t) \lif (q \lif \lnot s)}[(Given)]
}{%
  \subproof{%
    \pline[4]{t \land r}[(Assumption)]
  }{%
  }\\
}

\end{document}
```

[image: fitch-style proof without rules]

## EDIT

Also, whether or not this is useful depends on the system you are using, but the package also provides justifications of various kinds. For example, continuing the proof a little:

```
\fitchprf{%
  \pline[1]{r}[(Given)]\\
  \pline[2]{(t \land r) \lif s}[(Given)]\\
  \pline[3]{(p \lif t) \lif (q \lif \lnot s)}[(Given)]
}{%
  \subproof{%
    \pline[4]{t \land r}[(Assumption)]
  }{%
    \pline[5]{s}[\life{2}{4}]\\
    \pline[6]{t}[\lande{5}]\\
    \subproof{%
      \pline[7]{p \lif t}[(Assumption)]
    }{%
      \pline[8]{q \lif \lnot s}[\life{3}{7}]
    }
  }\\
}
```

produces

[image: proof with justifications]